# How can i solve blank spots in a SQL View?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, view, left-join

In my sqllite-excercises i have discovered the following problem:
I basically have three different Tables:

Subjects

| PRIMARY KEY(ID) | Subject |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Business |
| 2 | IT |
| 3 | Sports |

Participants

| PRIMARY KEY(ID) | Name | semester |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Meyer | 6 |
| 2 | Smith | 4 |
| 3 | Brown | 4 |
| 4 | White | 2 |
| 5 | Anthonie | 2 |
| 6 | Frankson | 2 |

They are referenced in the Table participants List

| SUBJECT.ID | Participant.ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 1 |

Now im supposted to create a VIEW that contains: The Participants.ID, Participants.Name and Subjects.Subject so i have a Table that shows the ID, the Name and the Subject the participant is visiting.

So far I did this:

```
CREATE VIEW[OVERVIEW]AS
   SELECT Participants.ID,
          Participants.Name,
          Subjects.Subject
         from Participants
         LEFT JOIN Subjects on Participants.ID = Subjects.ID;
```

As a result i get this:

| Participants.ID | Participant.Name | Subjects.Subject |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Meyer | Business |
| 2 | Smith | IT |
| 3 | Brown | Sports |
| 4 | White | None |
| 5 | Anthonie | None |
| 6 | Frankson | None |

And it makes sense since there are only three Subjects and i Leftjoined 6 Participants.ID on only 3 Subjects.Subject

How can i fill out the blank Subjects? So that the subjects for 4-6 are shown aswell?
I hope you can understand my problem and i declared it good enough.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't join `Participants` to `Subjects` because they are not directly related, so this `ON` clause:

```
on Participants.ID = Subjects.ID
```

does not make sense because the `ID`s of participants are not related to the `ID`s of the subjects.

You have the table `ParticipantsList` that can be used as an intermediate link between the other 2 tables:

```
SELECT p.ID, p.Name, s.Subject
FROM Participants p
LEFT JOIN ParticipantsList pl ON pl.Participant_ID = p.ID
LEFT JOIN Subjects s ON s.ID = pl.Subject_ID;
```

This will return all participants, even if they are not linked to any subject.

If you want only the participants for which there is at least 1 subject in the table `ParticipantsList` then you can use `INNER` joins.

For the sample data that you provide in your question in both cases the results are the same.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=524e2a772cf4dd55509ab3f134c8dc96).

Comment: thanks a lot for your time. 
Now i understood it and it worked well :-)